# Change a character string to a newline

Tags: css

The online catalog for my library displays the contents of music CDs on a single line with " -- " between each track. I'd like to modify the CSS so it was a little prettier. I'm not sure what the right terms to search for would be, or in fact if this is even possible.

Basically I want to take this:

> Content:
> Track 1. Flowers for Sarajevo (7:48) -- Track 2. Flowers for Sarajevo author's note, historical note, and brief biography of Vedran Smailovic (7:30) -- Track 3. "Streets of Sarajevo" (4:42)

Edit: generated HTML:

```
<div class="displayElementText CONTENTS">Track 1. Flowers for Sarajevo (7:48) -- Track 2. Flowers for Sarajevo author's note, historical note, and brief biography of Vedran Smailovic (7:30) -- Track 3. "Streets of Sarajevo" (4:42) -- Track 4. Tomaso Albinoni's Adagio in Gm, arranged by Vedran Smailovic (5:11) -- Track 5. Conversation with John McCutcheon (26:09) -- Track 6. Flowers for Sarajevo : story narrated by John McCutcheon with page-turn prompts (8:27).</div>
```

And replace it with:

> Content: Track 1. Flowers for Sarajevo (7:48)
>
> Track 2. Flowers for Sarajevo author's note, historical note, and brief biography of Vedran Smailovic (7:30)
>
> Track 3. "Streets of Sarajevo" (4:42)

Due to the way our catalog works the only tool I have access to is CSS... I'm hoping it's possible, but not holding my breath.

Comment: Could you provide an example of the HTML markup of such a catalog entry, too?

Comment: if it's only text here is no way with CSS to transform character in to new lines ... unless there is few things in your HTML that might help to find a workaround .. but for me the solution would be the use of JS/jQuery to replace the `--` with a line break

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how CSS relates to this but assuming you have an array of songs like:

`const songs = ["Flowers for Sarajevo", "Flowers for Sarajevo author's note, historical note, and brief biography of Vedran Smailovic", "Streets of Sarajevo"]`

you could do something like that:

html:
`<ul id="tracklist"></ul>`

js:

```
const tracklist = document.getElementById('tracklist');
const renderSongInPlaylist = (song, i) => {
   const li = document.createElement('li');
   li.textContent = `Track ${i}: ${song}`;
   tracklist.appendChild(li);
}
tracklist.forEach(renderSongInPlaylist)
```

Hope it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve this only using CSS. You can use some JavaScript to replace `--` with a `<br/>`

```
var tracks = document.querySelector('.displayElementText.CONTENTS')
tracks.innerHTML = tracks.innerText.replace(/ -- /, '<br/>')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll start with the straight-forward answer: CSS doesn't allow to edit element's text content.

**However** - if we can cheat - there are a couple of things that might work:

1. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24489273/3103891) was the closest thing I've found to actually use only CSS.
   It uses `\A` escape sequence, but it does require to manually edit the whole text (or using the next method) and it's absolute cheating, as far as I'm concerned.
   Anyways, this is how to implement it:

```css
div:before {
    content: "Content: Track 1. Flowers for Sarajevo (7:48) \A Track 2. Flowers for Sarajevo author's note, historical note, and brief biography of Vedran Smailovic (7:30) \A Track 3. \"Streets of Sarajevo\" (4:42) \A";
    white-space: pre;
    font-size: 12pt;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

div {
  font-size: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
Content: Track 1. Flowers for Sarajevo (7:48) -- Track 2. Flowers for Sarajevo author's note, historical note, and brief biography of Vedran Smailovic (7:30) -- Track 3. "Streets of Sarajevo" (4:42)
</div>
```

2. The easiest way to handle this would be using a regular expression and replacing all the `--`. If JavaScript is really not an option, you can at least manipulate the text with it and use the first method.