# Text wrapping in the wrong place

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

I have the text `Application->Welcome` and when the screen becomes too small I want it to cut off either before or after the arrow. But none of the css `word-wrap` values do this.

What I want to happen when the screen becomes too small:

```
Application->
Welcome
```

What actually happens when the screen becomes too small:

```
Application-
>Welcome
```

How do I make it so the wrap happens either before or after the arrow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use a 'NON-BREAKING HYPHEN' (U+2011)
 and 'ZERO WIDTH SPACE' (U+200B) to control the break behaviour:

```
Application&#x200B;&#x2011>&#x200B;Welcome
```

Another is to use an actual 'RIGHTWARDS ARROW' (U+2192):

```
Application&#x200B;&#x2192;&#x200B;Welcome
```

The ZWS inserted between the arrow and the words ensure places where the line can be broken, without otherwise affecting your layout.

Yet another, to create `<span>` elements with appropriate `white-space` CSS.

Comment: Out of the answers I've gotten, using the NON-BREAKING HYPHEN delivered the best result, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately such a thing is not supported by css, but fear not!

You have a couple of options at hand:

- Add a space before and/or after the arrow so that the browser prefers to break on the space character rather than on the middle of the arrow.
- Add a zero width charcater (U+200B unicode code) instead of a space.
- Place `Application->` and `Welcome` in different html tags, inside a single tag. Set those tags to have a css property like `word-break:none`

There is [lengthy discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24489931/11869748) related to this problem but there is no way to do what you want without adapting a little.

Hope this helps! ;)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider using a single [Unicode](https://www.key-shortcut.com/en/writing-systems/35-symbols/arrows) character.

```html
Application&#x2192;Welcome
```

Comment: Appreciate your answer. For some reason the text is now not wrapping at all. This is also not what I would want to use because it looks a lot different.

Answer (score 0):

`word-wrap` determines wrapping/breaking inside a word. I doubt `->` would be considered a word. You need to use `white-space` instead, specifically it's value `nowrap`.

```
Application<span style="white-space: nowrap">-&gt;</span>Welcome
```

Or a better/nicer solution would not to "build" an arrow out of separate characters. Consider using the Unicode character [RIGHTWARDS ARROW (→)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2192/index.htm). If your HTML doesn't have a UTF-8 encoding it can be inserted with the entity `&rarr;`.