# How to do a linebreak always after one of a couple chars when a certain length would be exceeded?

Tags: javascript, html, css, line-breaks, paragraph

```js
var array = ["9999999999999999+9999999999999999=2,3+16","666666666666666666666+3=666666666666666666669","3x3=9","2,3-2,1=0,2"];
var table = document.createElement('TABLE');
    var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
        table.border = '0';
        table.appendChild(tableBody);
        
function makeArr()
{
        var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("myTable1");
        tableBody.innerHTML = "";
            
        for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++)
        {
            
        var tr = document.createElement('TR');
            tableBody.appendChild(tr);
            
        var td = document.createElement('TD')
            td.width = '275';
            
            td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(array[i]));

            tr.appendChild(td);
            myTableDiv.appendChild(table);
        }
        
    var z = document.getElementById("myTable1");
    var tablewidth = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("myTable2")).getPropertyValue('width');
    var tableheight = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("myTable2")).getPropertyValue('height');
    z.style.width = tablewidth;
    z.style.height = tableheight;
}
```

```css
.tables {
  display: flex;
}

#myTable1,
#myTable2{
    background: #EEEEEB;
    border: none;
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: auto
}

#myTable1 td,
#myTable2 td{
    text-align: right;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<input type="button"value="MakeTable"onClick="makeArr()">
<div class="tables" id="tables" >
    <div id="myTable1">

    </div>
    
    <div id="myTable2">
      <table id="myTable2">
      <th>Always here,same size</th>
          <tr>
          <td>these</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td>are</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td>just</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td>contents</td>
          </tr>

      </table>
   </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Similar to the functionality of the css tag "overflow" I want to have linebreaks if the container would overflow horizontally, and always end the lines on one of 5 specific chars (+,-,*,/,=). overflowing vertically will be solved with scrolling(overflow tag should provide that)

That's kind of how I want it to look:

[image]

Also how to convert into exponential notation when the max permitted length is exceeded?

The maximum permitted length is defined in JS.

Sidenode: Also later the goal is to be able to drag the whole thing around with drag&drop and make it transparent for some nice effect.

Comment: Use `.toExponential()` to convert a number to its exponential form. As for adding line breaks when a certain length is exceeded, that is a very vague statement. Please describe exactly what conditions under which you would want this to happen.

Comment: thanks! somewhat like the CSS tag "overflow" but that doesnt provide that functionality...Instead of overflowing the container (-padding?) it has to do linebreaks and always end with (+,-,*,/,=). the maximum char length of entered numbers will be declared elsewere and if its to long, converted to exponential

Comment: Why you have commas in your mathematical expressions?

Comment: I copied it from the windows Calculator, I think its because its in german we write 2 point 5 as 2,5 not 2.5

Comment: Minor note: you have two elements with `id="myTable2`. IDs must be unique.

Answer (score 1):

A complete solution is fairly involved so rather than writing it all for you, I'll give you a list of things to investigate further:

Putting answers in bold on a line by themselves: Since every answer (i.e. the right side of every equation) should always be on a line by itself, use `.split(/=/)` to split the equation into two halves. You can put the right half into, say, a `<div>` and use CSS to format that div to be bold.

It looks like you've already figured out how to get the computed width of an element. You can use that to determine if the answer is too wide, in which case you can use `.toExponential()` to format it in exponential form before inserting it into the `<div>`.

As for the left side of the equation, if you want to determine which numbers that are too long to fit in one line and reformat that with `toExponential()`, that gets tricky because you now have to parse through each number, test its length, and decide whether to reformat it. Not impossible, but a pain.

Assuming you don't want to bother with that, and moving on to the task of making the left side of the equation wrap when necessary but only after one of `+,-,*,/` (it would not include `=` because the previous step of splitting the string will give you just the left side of the equation, up to but not including `=`): replace all instances of `[space][operator][space]` (e.g.  `+` ) with `&nbsp;[operator]&nbsp;[Unicode zero width space]`. This will ensure that when the line wraps, it only does so at the zero width space, but spaces (actually, non-breaking spaces) still appear around the operator. [See this answer for details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24489931/378779).

Comment: thanks very very much for the guideline =))) I see what I can do!