# html word wrap breaks on url around / or @

Tags: html, css

I am wondering what I can do to make my text break on a character such as on the @ or the / in a url on my page [when it hits the container width].

[image]

```css
div {
  width:200px;
  height:100%;
  background-color:palegreen;
}
p {
  background-color:green;
  overflow-wrap:break-word;
}
```

```html
<div>
  1abc/def/efg/hij/klmnoptu@vwxyz.com
  <br><br>
  2abc/def/efg/hij/klmnopqrsrejrweurhwjekrhjwekrhjwektu@vwxyz.com
  <br><br>
  3abc/def/efg hij/klmnopqrstuvwxyz.com


  <p>
    4abc/def/efg/hij/klmnoptu@vwxyz.com
  </p>
  <p>
    5abc/def/efg/hij/klmnopqrsrejrweurhwjekrhjwekrhjwektu@vwxyz.com
  </p>
  <p>
    6abc/def/efg hij/klmnopqrstu
  </p>
</div>
```

For a jsfiddle see : https://jsfiddle.net/Abeeee/e3u5xck4/1/

Is there a css facility to fix this - or is there a way to insert  tags into the text to wrap @ or / with?

> I would want something like....
>
> [image]

Comment: One possibility would be that you insert [`<wbr>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/wbr) elements in those places where you want to allow a break to occur.

Comment: Another would be to insert a _zero width non-joiner_ character in those positions, HTML entity `&zwnj;`

Comment: thanks - but this is a cms - I would need to insert these options using code (regex) - and I can't see how

Comment: This seems to be what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24489273/4548398

Comment: _"and I can't see how"_ - based on no more info than "is a cms", I doubt anyone here can tell you much more either.

Comment: .. sorry - meant I can't control what content is being put in to the CMS, so I would need to adjust that content output programmatically [using regex maybe]; I guess I can look at using regex to adjust "/" or "@" with <wbr>'s then.. although that won't sort out the line starting 5abc...

Comment: Basically, using CSS? No!

Answer (score -1):

Using `word-break: break-all;` will help with your issue and break the text up.

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break).

```css
div {
  width:200px;
  height:100%;
  background-color:palegreen;
  word-break: break-all;
}
p {
  background-color:green;
  overflow-wrap:break-word;
}
```

```html
<div>
  1abc/def/efg/hij/klmnoptu@vwxyz.com
  <br><br>
  2abc/def/efg/hij/klmnopqrsrejrweurhwjekrhjwekrhjwektu@vwxyz.com
  <br><br>
  3abc/def/efg hij/klmnopqrstuvwxyz.com


  <p>
    4abc/def/efg/hij/klmnoptu@vwxyz.com
  </p>
  <p>
    5abc/def/efg/hij/klmnopqrsrejrweurhwjekrhjwekrhjwektu@vwxyz.com
  </p>
  <p>
    6abc/def/efg hij/klmnopqrstu
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: ... thanks but doesn't break on the obvious @ or / characters